# failed to display user's data in react native

Tags: image, api, react-native, profile

I am building an app in react native CRNA and I got this error after I call for the registered user's profile picture.

> calls to `require` expect exactly 1 string literal argument, but this
>   was found: `require(this.state.pict)`

I'm kinda confused how to call the item of user's info from the API. This is my code to get the user's data.

```
fetch('someurl', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers:{
                Authorization: 'token',
            }
        })
        .then((response)=> response.json())
        .then((responseJson)=> {
            this.setState({
                students: responseJson.data,
                loading: false,
            })
        })
        .catch((error)=>{
            console.log(error);
        });
```

I put that code on the `componentDidMount()` and call `this.state.pict` in the image source but got the previous error. Can someone please tell me what's wrong? I'm so stuck.. thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

React-native supports two types of image sources, local and network.

For local sources you use require. For example:

```
<Image source={require('main/assets/images/your-image.jpg')}/>
```

For network resources you must use uri object. For example:

```
<Image source={{uri:'https://imgur.com/gallery/Fepmd4K'}/>
```

Notice that source for local images accepts require with string passed as a parameter, while source for network images require object with uri parameter.

You can read more here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images

Regarding your problem, first try to `console.log` `this.state.pic` and see what format is it in and match that with the above examples and it should work.

Comment: oh thank you so much for your response.. i just found out that the picture is null by calling it on console.log.. is that the reason? but i tried to show only `<View></View>` `if this.state.pict == null || this.state.pict == ""` and got the same error

Comment: View doesn't render anything if there isn't anything inside it. Try to put <Text>your text</Text> inside to check if this is true, but it probably is.

Also, try logging `this.state.students`, it seems that that is where you saved your response data.

Comment: oh no.. i tried to console.log the `this.state.students` and got nothing at all.. is it because I made a mistake in saving my response data?

Comment: Log every step to see if it's correct. Does response.json() returns something valid?  If yes, you should have something in this.state.students, start there and work further. I'm not sure where you are fetching this, so does it trigger correctly, do you have proper request sent at all?